# Git - I can push/pull but not clone

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Using bit bucket I can push and pull a reposotory, but I cant clone a new one.

I'm using SSH.

As a work around, I'm creating a local repo and adding the bit bucket repo as a remote and this works!

I'm using Git Extension as my local client

Error following clone

> FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Git Config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:lstm/ldap-test.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: so your remote uses http?

Comment: Provide your git clone command line, and also contents of .gitconfig from your working local repo.

Comment: And the error output after you git clone

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In the git `.config` you have `git@bitbucket.org:lstm/ldap-test.git` (i.e., access through git protocol). But you said that you are using SSH. 
Configurations are clearly misaligned: you should either update your `.config` file providing the full SSH URL, or set git for not using SSH.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but I thought I was using git over SSH? The repository the config is from works (using ssh keys), this is the one I setup manually rather than clone.

Comment: `git@bitbucket.org:lstm/ldap-test.git` is certainly an SSH URL (SCP-like in terms of `git`).